Node: Why are `os.constants.errno` values positive, while `util.getSystemErrorName` expects negative errnos?
All the values in os.constants.errno are positive, e.g.
{
  E2BIG: 7,
  EACCES: 13,
  EADDRINUSE: 48,
  EADDRNOTAVAIL: 49,
  EAFNOSUPPORT: 47,
  EAGAIN: 35,
  EALREADY: 37,
  EBADF: 9,
  EBADMSG: 94,
  // ...
}

Meanwhile, util.getSystemErrorMap and util.getSystemErrorName have negative integer codes.
> util.getSystemErrorName(os.constants.errno.E2BIG)
Uncaught:
RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "err" is out of range. It must be a negative integer. Received 7
    at Object.getSystemErrorName (node:util:343:11) {
  code: 'ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE'
}

> util.getSystemErrorName(-os.constants.errno.E2BIG)
'E2BIG'

Node's documentation on error objects says:

error.errno

<number>

The error.errno property is a negative number which corresponds to the error code defined in libuv Error handling.
On Windows the error number provided by the system will be normalized by libuv.
To get the string representation of the error code, use util.getSystemErrorName(error.errno).

Which sign is supposed to be considered canonical? What is the purpose of this inconsistency?

Note that os.constants.errno and util.getSystemErrorName are different namespaces. utils uses libuv to get error names, whereas os uses the operating system's error codes. Both are canonical within their namespace.

NodeJS os.constants.errno are based on Linux standardized error codes, which can be found on detailed man pages like linux.die.net.
